# Orthonormal projection contracts inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I wonder if an orthonormal projection $P^2=P$ in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, contracts its inner product i.e.

$\langle PW,V \rangle \leq \langle W,V \rangle $

for every pair of elements $W,V \in \mathcal{H}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily. You might have $(W, V)=0$ and $(PW, V)\ne 0$ for example. Consider in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the vectors $W=(-1, 1), V=(1, 1)$ and the projector 
$$P(x, y)=(x, 0).$$

Answer (score 1):

If you write $W$ as $PW + (1-P)W$, the answer would seem to turn on whether $\langle (1-P)W, V \rangle$ is positive or not, and it would depend on the situation.